# Is that possible to get location type like "restaurant" using MKLocalSearch

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapkit

I'm currently using MKLocalSearch to search locations. I noticed that in the Apple Map, there are some icons displayed in the search results indicating that the location is a restaurant, an airport, or a hospital. I want to implement that functionality as well. So I just want to know whether we could get the location type from the search results of MKLocalSearch?

Comment: Yeah, if you [openInMaps](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapitem/1452239-openinmaps) the resulting `MKMapItem` produced by `MKLocalSearch`, you see that icon you mention. I don't know if there's some private `MKMapItem` property of which Maps is availing itself, or whether it's doing some other API call. But I see no obvious public property for either the `MKMapItem` nor its `MKPlacemark` that yields this information...

Answer (score 0):

We can query out categories of locations from local search using the following code

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "coffee"
```

Apple doesn't provide any methods in MKMapItem to retrieve the details of the classification like restaurant, coffee etc.

Answer (score 0):

The next best thing you can do is using

```
MKMapItem.pointOfInterestCategory
```

Which sometimes is nil, even if Apple Maps shows a category.
You can show a different icon based on the category.

Also be aware that you can use `MKLocalSearch.Request.pointOfInterestFilter` and search for specific categories or exclude specific categories.

With a **slightly different approach** and starting with iOS 16, you might have a look at MKFeatureAnnotation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapfeatureannotation

Here the user can tap on this small Icons shown by MKMapView.
Which `MKMapFeatureAnnotation` you get `var iconStyle: MKIconStyle?` which contains the actual icon shown by apple including the color.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I do:

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "YOUR_CATEGORY" + text
```

`text` being the user-entered text.